# socket try connection exception

Tags: python, sockets, socketexception, sleekxmpp

I am using [sleekxmpp](http://sleekxmpp.com/api/clientxmpp.html) to send python responses to an instant messenger. I have an active and a backup server.

Currently I am connection to the active server like described in the docs.

```
if xmpp.connect(('myserver', myport)):

    xmpp.process(block=True)
    print("Done")
else:
    print("Unable to connect.")
```

Lately I received a `[WinError 10061] ConnectionRefusedError`. I don´t want to manually change the server to the backup-server, so I try to implement a `try-except` block.

This is what I got so far

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.connect(('myserver', myport))
except:
    print("not able to connect to myserver")
```

After executing the script I get the error message with the print. So far so good. But now I want to implement a second connect if the first connection to the main-server fails.

I am pretty new to exceptions and sockets in python, I don´t know how to achieve this. I tried the block below but the script automatically aborts with the print from the try block.

```
try:
    s.connect(('active_server', myport))
except:
    s.connect(('backup_server', myport))
    print("not able to connect to both servers")
```

Could you give some assistance?

**EDIT:**
I have a working solution now, but this seems to be very bad coding.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.connect(('active_server', myport))
    xmpp.connect(('active_server', myport))

except:
    print("Can´t connect to active_server, try to connect to backup_server...")
    xmpp.connect(('backup_server', myport))
    

xmpp.process(block=True)
```

First `xmpp.process` is necessary. Second `s.connect()` I think just connects to the socket, but `xmpp.connect()` is necessary to connect the python script to the IM server.
In other words: I check if I can connect to a`ctive_server:myport` generally, if yes, I connect via `xmpp.connect()`. But there must be a much better solution than mine

Comment: Does it abort? If the `backup_server` connection is successful, then the print statement will fire, otherwise you will see an unhandled `ConnectionError`

Comment: @C.Nivs see my edit

Comment: If `xmpp` will connect to the server, do you need the socket connection? Seems like you are opening two socket handles to the same address. I'm not too familiar with `xmpp` so I'm reading through the documentation at the moment

Comment: if I remove the ```s.connect()``` I get the ConnectionRefusedError, but the script don´t jumps into the except block